# how to export a list of products in Magento that belongs to a specific category only?

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I'm using Magento 1.7.0, I want to export all the products whose category_Id is 85. Mean I have to export all products who belongs to a category having Id is 85. I could not find any such attribute/label in Export filter option. Any help Would be great appreciable.

Comment: By default it is not in magento. you can code for this or use some type of extension like this one [http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bulk-category-import-export.html]

Comment: It redirecting me to a "404 page not found" page . Any other such plugins u know ?

Comment: remove the last character `]`.